# Не работает прокси для тг бота (пишу на python, библиотека — telebot)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот, proxy

При попытке включения, появляется следующая ошибка:

```console
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)
```

Или ей подобные.

Вот, что прописал для прокси:

```
from telebot import types, apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token='токен:)', threaded=False)
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5://195.168.10.9:28354'}

bot.infinity_polling(timeout=10, long_polling_timeout = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

документация

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5://userproxy:password@proxy_address:port'}
```

но если не работает попробуйте вот это

```
apihelper.proxy = {'https':'socks5h://userproxy:password@proxy_address:port'}
```